# Custom React Hook not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use below custom hook but it's not working as expected

CustomHook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { createAPIInstance } from '../utils/api'
import { getBaseUrl } from '../utils/functions'

const BASE_URL = getBaseUrl()

const useGetAPI = (endpoint) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const api = createAPIInstance()

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await api.get(`${BASE_URL}${endpoint}`)
    setData(response.data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  return data
}

export {
  useGetAPI
}
```

Here is the custom hook usage

app.js

```
function App() {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const details = useGetAPI('/some-api-endpoint')
      setDetails(details)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

Error on chrome console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at invariant
```

React Version: 16.13.1
React-Dom Version: 16.13.1

Comment: I tried to follow the example which has been provided on React official docs, but that too is throwing the same error. This looks simple but not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

For `app.js` :

Why are you initialise a function in the same location ?

Example :

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
      const details = useGetAPI('/some-api-endpoint')
      setDetails(details)
}

useEffect(async () => {
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

You don't `export default` your function.

Example :

```js
export default function App() {
```

For `CustomHook` :

You don't say as your function is using `async` values.

Example :

```js
const useGetAPI = async (endpoint) => {

useEffect(async () => {
```